# SSH into Azure Logic App using the Advanced Tools in the Logic App configuration

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureportal

Is it possible to SSH into a Logic App using Kudu (now called Advanced Tools), in the Logic App configuration?

I have no access restrictions on the Logic App, as shown below

[image: Logic App configuration]

The above configuration has always allowed me to SSH into other types of App services, but when I try to do so for a Logic App, I am getting a *403 - Forbidden : The web app you have attempted to reach has blocked your access*, as below.

[image: error message]

Comment: We have tested in our local environment, by creating a standard logic app, stateful work flow (with http request as trigger) & we have tried doing SSH into the kudu console from advanced tools in portal we are able to access it as well with no issues. 

Here is the screenshot for reference :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6l8o.png

Comment: As you mentioned in the screenshot, stating that the access restrictions of the web app is already in off state can you try troubleshooting the 403 errors by  running  the ['Availability & Performance report ']( https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4zEa.png)under 'Diagnose & solve problems ' in the portal.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT thanks for your replies! I am getting the exact same error when accessing the Logic App public URL, and I noticed by reading your reply, that I don't have a workflow created just yet. Is it the case that, even if the Logic App shows as being running, it will be inaccessible until a workflow is created?

Comment: I tried to create either a stateful, or stateless workflow, and it is failing : https://imgur.com/a/a3mic6s

Comment: i have removed the earlier created work flow tried accessing the logic app public url it is also succeeding without  any issue & also i am able to access the kudu console as well .  Having tried generating the availability and performance report under Diagnose & solve problems ?

Comment: I think it is a bug with this particular Logic App, because I am able to create workflows on other Logic Apps. However, I have the same issue when accessing this other Logic App public URL and kudu. For the first Logic App we spoke of, I have tried to generate that report, and it shows no errors : https://imgur.com/a/rddKl1s

Comment: Could you please file a discussion over [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/)  or  create a technical support ticket by following the [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) where technical support team would help you in troubleshooting the issue from platform end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is happening because the storage account is not accessible on public endpoint. On Azure portal, this can be configured by selecting the *Network* blade in the storage account configuration, and by ticking the *Selected Networks* option. Even granting access from Azure trusted services, shown as well in the configuration below, will result in the initial error when SSHing into the Logic App.

[image: Storage account configuration, with network security restrictions]

It is thus necessary to either connect the [Logic App to the storage account via service/private endpoint](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure/deploying-standard-logic-app-to-storage-account-behind-firewall/ba-p/2626286), or to create an [Integration Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment), which will then enable the Logic App to access the storage account.